# Document Model Fields Sinatra

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, documentation

Is there some automated way to document fields names and types inside of the models in Sinatra app, something equivalent to annotate gem in rails?

Example:

```
# == Schema Info
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                  :integer(11)    not null, primary key
#  name                :string         not null
#  gender              :string         not null
#  age                 :float
#
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Comment: There aren't any models in the Sinatra framework, you add those yourself by picking something like ActiveRecord or Sequel etc.

Comment: If you're already using `ActiveRecord` in Sinatra, have you tried using the `annotate` gem to see if it works on your Sinatra app?